# Recuperar uma propriedade de um arquivo .properties diretamente com thymeleaf

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

Em um arquivo .properties tenho uma propriedade com a versão do sistema.

Existe alguma forma do Thymeleaf recuperar essa propriedade diretamente?

Quero utilizar no rodapé que é um fragmento utilizado em todas as paginas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quem interessar possa.
O Spring boot configura automaticamente o thymeleaf. 
Com isso os arquivos messages.properties são automaticamente identificados (desde que estejam no diretorio padrão. O mesmo do application.properties).
Basta para isso no arquivo hmtl incluir #{nome.chave} ta tag especifica.
Exemplo:

```
<p class="navbar-text hidden-xs" th:text="|Versão - #{home.versao}|"></p>
```